# Trim spine points (AN)

Tags: animation-nodes

Does anybody perhaps know how to trim out these annoying last points of the spline for a more eye pleasing result?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GPkb.png

thx in advance!

Comment: hello, could you please be more precise about what you want to do?

Comment: Hi, when I play this animation all points outside the highlighted white circle (see added image) bounce up and down on the rhythm of the sound input. The part in the white circle stays unaffected, I would like to remove those points so the whole circle shows bouncing activity. I hope I explained it a bit better now.

Comment: so if you delete them with X > Dissolve Vertices, does it answer?